# Chrome Extension: Inject Javascript to set variables

Tags: variables, google-chrome-extension

How can I inject a `<script>` to my document which will initialize a variable?

content_script:

```
$("body").append('<script type="text/javascript">myvar="hi there";</script>');
```

When I do this, the variable `myvar` is not recognized...
If I add a simple `alert(500);` I get the alert.

Basically I just want to pass a variable from the extension the document to use it there.

Comment: Covered in [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Comment: actually you are right. jQuery can't do the job as it seems; but method 2 from your [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) does

Answer (score -1):

add var

```
$("body").append('<script type="text/javascript">var myvar="hi there";</script>');
```

Comment: I'd be glad if it was that easy. Not working

Comment: hehe if i do this from console it is working, youre version also works.... when do you inject / execute the code